# Unable to resolve @SpringBootTest with a maven dependency with scope test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, spring-boot-test

I added [this repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-test/2.2.4.RELEASE) to `pom.xml`, but `IntelliJ` fails to resolve `org.springframework.boot.test`:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

[image]

However, after adding the library to `classpath`, it happens to work:

[image] 
[image]
[image]

What's so special about this repository that I should add it manually?

*EDIT:*

`<scope></scope>` was causing this problem. I had no idea of what it actually does, and it made `IntelliJ` ignore my `main` directory.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted it manually from the local maven repository. If it still not working. Add the older version to pom.xml.
Hope it work

Answer (score 1):

After adding the dependency to the pom.xml do a MAVEN REIMPORT. If it doesn't solve, go to main menu and do invalidate cache/restart ide. Then you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems :** 
I was also facing the same issue but with the Gradle. 
The @SpringBootTest and all JUnit dependency like @Test were not resolving.
In my build.gradle, I had dependency like this

```
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

**Solution**

The problem is that the test dependency is not visible to the folder in which your test class is present. You need to have it in the same structure as shown below.
[image]

**More things you can do** 
Then telling IntelliJ about my test folder as in the image below so that I can directly use the shortcut to create the test class at the right location.
[image]

After that to create a test class for a particular class, on a mac I use CMD+Shift+T and then select the test folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue wiht my project. I tried Maven->update project(Alt-F5). This will update the maven dependencies once and builds your project.

It helped me resolving the issue.